# Android and HTML5 CACHE.MANIFEST

Tags: android

I have searched with google, and can't find out how much of CACHE.MANIFEST android supports, and what versions of android that supports it.

Anyone out there that have more knowledge on the subject???

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get a flashlight and flashcard app to work offline for iOS 4.2 and Android 2.2:

https://github.com/coolaj86/iphone-html5-offline-app-demo

http://coolaj86.info/iphone-html5-offline-app-demo/

Does that help?